# C# Enum validate from list of values

Tags: c#, enums

I saw somewhere (cannot find it anymore) that you can check the existence of an enum value from an enum item with a specific list of items. Ex. below - "Available = doc | xls | csv"

But the following code does not seem to work.  I'm expecting the results to be = xls instead of doc, since it is in the list of "Available" values.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Niki

Button Code:

```
protected void btnTest01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestEnum01 result1 = TestEnum01.xls;
    TestEnum02 result2 = TestEnum02.xls;
    TestEnum03 result3 = TestEnum03.xls;

    if (result1 != TestEnum01.Available)
    {
        result1 = TestEnum01.doc;
    }

    if (result2 != TestEnum02.Available)
    {
        result2 = TestEnum02.doc;
    }

    if (result3 != TestEnum03.Available)
    {
        result3 = TestEnum03.doc;
    }

    this.txtTest01_Results.Text =
        String.Format("01: Result = {0}, Available = {1}\r\n\r\n02: Result = {2}, Available = {3}\r\n\r\n03: Result = {4}, Available = {5}",
        result1.ToString(), TestEnum01.Available,
        result2.ToString(), TestEnum02.Available,
        result3.ToString(), TestEnum03.Available);
    }
```

ENUMS

```
public enum TestEnum01
{
    doc = 1,
    txt = 2,
    xls = 4,
    csv = 8,
    unknown = 5,
    Available = doc | xls | csv
}

public enum TestEnum02
{
    doc,
    txt,
    xls,
    csv,
    unknown,
    Available = doc | xls | csv
}

public enum TestEnum03
{
    doc,
    txt,
    xls,
    csv,
    unknown,
    Available = TestEnum03.doc | TestEnum03.xls | TestEnum03.csv
}
```

RESULTS:

```
01: Result = doc, Available = Available
02: Result = doc, Available = csv
03: Result = doc, Available = csv
```

Comment: It is not really clear what is your question. Can you explain it better? Also those 3 enums are confusing. Are they shows your attempts or..?

Comment: My question is, can I check an enum item if it exists using another enum item with a list of values.  In the example above, I'm checking ifof TestEnum01.xls exists in the list of values in TestEnum01.Available.  But the "if (result1 != TestEnum01.Available)" does not seem to work.

Comment: Use HasFlag method `if(result.HasFlag(TestEnum01.xls))` and to get nice `ToString` conversion, use `FlagsAttribute`

Comment: Thanks.  I used the HasFlag to default the value to doc if enum is unknown or not in the list of Available values. "if (!TestEnum01.Available.HasFlag(input) || (input == TestEnum01.unknown))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum01
{
    doc = 1,
    txt = 2,
    xls = 4,
    csv = 8,
    unknown = 5,
    Available = doc | xls | csv
}
```

Then to test it :

```
TestEnum01 test = TestEnum01.doc | TestEnum01.txt;
bool isDoc = (test & TestEnum01.doc) == TestEnum01.doc;
```

Note that in your example, you will have a problem with `unknown` value, since binary wise, 1 | 4 = 5 ... And that means doc and xls produces unknown... To avoid this kind of problems, I prefer to use a direct bit-shift notation :

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum01
{
    unknown = 0,
    doc = 1 << 0,
    txt = 1 << 1,
    xls = 1 << 2,
    csv = 1 << 3,
    Available = doc | xls | csv
}
```

If you just want to test for a particular flag, you can just use the [`HasFlag()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
TestEnum01 test = TestEnum01.doc | TestEnum01.txt;
bool isDoc = test.HasFlag(TestEnum01.doc);
```

Comment: Sharped, how can I use that logic to test if the value I am passing (ex. TestEnum01.xls) exists in TestEnum01.Available?

Comment: just use the line bool isDoc = ... or HasFlag()

Comment: Thanks.  I used the HasFlag to default the value to doc if enum is unknown or not in the list of Available values. "if (!TestEnum01.Available.HasFlag(input) || (input == TestEnum01.unknown))" where input=TestEnum01.xls for example.